# React login/sign-up form toggle issues

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, forms

I am attempting to toggle between a login field and a signup field on a form such as shown here https://codepen.io/guycode/pen/VwaKVrb .

My issue is that I am using React and having trouble altering them through the js and CSS like I've got it set up within my SignIn component. Currently, my form is just displaying them both and focusing on my #login div when I click login but doesn't hide the #inputs-section.

**SignUp Component**

```js
import React from 'react';


export default class SignUp extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = true;
    script.src = "./build/js/components/signup/logmein.js";
    this.div.appendChild(script);
    }

    render() {
        const onClick = () => {
            this.props.login();
            console.log('rich');
        }
        return (
        
             <div className='sign-up'>
                 <div className="SignUp" ref={el => (this.div = el)}></div>
                 <table className='sign-up-form'>
                    <tbody>
                    <div class="gecko-signup__tabs">    
                        <button id="gecko-signup" data-selected="yes">Sign Up</button>
                    <button id="gecko-login" data-selected=""><a href="#login">Log In</a></button></div>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p id="signUpFree">Sign Up for Free</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <div id="inputs-section">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input id="first" placeholder="First Name*" /></td>
                                <td><input id="last" placeholder="Last Name*" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <div class="field-wrap">
                         <label>
                           Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                         </label>
                                 <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
                                 </div>
                                  <div class="field-wrap">
                               <label>
                              Password<span class="req">*</span>
                                </label>
                           <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
                         </div>
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="2"><input id="getStarted" type="submit" value="Get Started" onClick={onClick}/></td>
                        </tr>
                        </div>
                        <div id="login">   
                        <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
          
                         <form action="/" method="post">
          
                         <div class="field-wrap">
                         <label>
                           Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                         </label>
                                 <input type="email"required autocomplete="off"/>
                                 </div>
          
                              <div class="field-wrap">
                               <label>
                              Password<span class="req">*</span>
                                </label>
                           <input type="password"required autocomplete="off"/>
                         </div>
                             <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                         <button class="button button-block">Log In</button>
                         </form>
                     </div>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );  
    }
}
```

**relevant css**

```css
$body-bg: #c1bdba;
$form-bg: #13232f;
$white: #ffffff;

$main: #1ab188;
$main-light: lighten($main,5%);
$main-dark: darken($main,5%);

$gray-light: #a0b3b0;
$gray: #ddd;

$thin: 300;
$normal: 400;
$bold: 600;
$br: 4px;

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:$main;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  &:hover {
    color:$main-dark;
  }
}

.form {
  background:rgba($form-bg,.9);
  padding: 40px;
  max-width:600px;
  margin:40px auto;
  border-radius:$br;
  box-shadow:0 4px 10px 4px rgba($form-bg,.3);
}

.gecko-signup__tabs {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 40px 0;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:15px;
    background:rgba($gray-light,.25);
    color:$gray-light;
    font-size:20px;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    &:hover {
      background:$main-dark;
      color:$white;
    }
  }
  .active a {
    background:$main;
    color:$white;
  }
}

.gecko-signup__tabs > div:last-child {
  display:none;
}


h1 {
  text-align:center;
  color:$white;
  font-weight:$thin;
  margin:0 0 40px;
}

label {
  position:absolute;
  transform:translateY(6px);
  left:13px;
  color:rgba($white,.5);
  transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size:22px;
  .req {
    margin:2px;
    color:$main;
  }
}

label.active {
  transform:translateY(50px);
  left:2px;
  font-size:14px;
  .req {
    opacity:0;
  }
}

label.highlight {
    color:$white;
}

input, textarea {
  font-size:22px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:none;
  background-image:none;
  border:1px solid $gray-light;
  color:$white;
  border-radius:0;
  transition:border-color .25s ease-in-out, box-shadow .25s ease-in-out;
  &:focus {
        outline:0;
        border-color:$main;
  }
}

textarea {
  border:2px solid $gray-light;
  resize: vertical;
}

.field-wrap {
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:40px;
}

.top-row {
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  > div {
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    margin-right:4%;
    &:last-child { 
      margin:0;
    }
  }
}

.button {
  border:0;
  outline:none;
  border-radius:0;
  padding:15px 0;
  font-size:2rem;
  font-weight:$bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:.1em;
  background:$main;
  color:$white;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  &:hover, &:focus {
    background:$main-dark;
  }
}

.button-block {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top:-20px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

**linked js using react-script-tag**

```js
$('.sign-up-form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
  
    var $this = $(this),
        label = $this.prev('label');
  
        if (e.type === 'keyup') {
              if ($this.val() === '') {
            label.removeClass('active highlight');
          } else {
            label.addClass('active highlight');
          }
      } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
          if( $this.val() === '' ) {
              label.removeClass('active highlight'); 
              } else {
              label.removeClass('highlight');   
              }   
      } else if (e.type === 'focus') {
        
        if( $this.val() === '' ) {
              label.removeClass('highlight'); 
              } 
        else if( $this.val() !== '' ) {
              label.addClass('highlight');
              }
      }
  
  });
  
  $('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    
    target = $(this).attr('href');
  
    $('#login').not(target).hide();
    
    $(target).fadeIn(600);
    
  });
```

Does anybody have any takes on what might be keeping it from hiding either the #inputs-section or getting them to toggle cleaner?

Comment: I should add here is the repo in case that helps https://github.com/guycode/gecko-repo

Comment: From what I understand of your issue description, your UI is displaying both the "Sign Up" form ***and*** the "Log In" form? Is this correct? Your linked codepen appears to correctly switch between these two forms for me, i.e. I don't seem to see two forms visible at the same time, the first and last name fields hide when viewing the "Log In" form.

Comment: Drew the codepen is an example of what I’m trying to replicate within my project. In my code they are both displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use react-router-dom. and create two routes one for sign up and one for sign in.
Since its single page, there will not be any full page reload and smooth transition.
and your fiddle link is broken.
From the code, it seems you are new to react. Instead of using jquery and vanilla javascript please use react state for toggle functionality.
have a boolean field in state and just update its value and have a conditional inside the render jsx
and I would also recommend you to checkout FORMIK & YUP library for form and error handling in react